# Calling a web service from a front end process

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

Our department will have a front end process to call a web service to retrieve data.

The data retrieved will be in the form of a collection in the web service.

What I want to know is possible is that once the call is made to the service method, can that method initiate a separate call to another web service (with the retrieved data in the collection) without the front end application having any involvement to call that other web service?

I'm thinking that maybe the front end application **has** to call the other web service to post the spotcheckcollection data instead of a separate call to the web service as explained above.

As an example, here is the code...

```
// Web service method
public SpotCheckCollection GetSpotCheckInventory(int locationID, int extractID)
        {
            SpotCheckCollection spotCheckCollection = null;

            try
            {
                // Front-end calls this method putting the data in the spotCheckCollection  variable.
                spotCheckCollection = SpotCheckCollectionGateway.GetData(locationID, extractID);

                // Can a separate web service call go here pushing the spotCheckCollection data to that web service instead of the front end application doing it?
                // TODO: Call Velocitor web service to push the data to them from the JWALK call.

                return null; // TODO: Remove after I set up call to Velocitor.

        }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking.  Any code can call a web service, so if the server-side code for the first service needs to call the second service then just go ahead and change it to call the second service.  If it can't, then this client-side code can certainly call the second service.

Comment: The client doesn't need to be involved. The second service just needs to have an operation that supports a SpotCheckCollection. You would handle it that same as you did calling the first web service, you would just doing it from service to service instead of client to service.

Comment: Thanks bsayegh. The second service does have that operation available. Bear in mind that the "GetSpotCheckInventory" method would be called by the front-end application, thereby populating the spotCheckCollection variable. When that happens, a call to the second web service would be right beneath the code after retrieving the spotCheckCollection.